# How to keep changes in Head by removing other changes(even in remote) in git?

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

1. I made a branch from main. say **TestBranch**.
2. did some changes on **TestBranch** and push them to remote.
3. **check out to old commit.**
4. did some changes and committed them.

So I need to keep the changes currently in Head ,and remove above all commits from where I checkout in (3)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

You'll probably want to make a new branch name, or forcibly update some existing branch name, then use this branch name with `git push` or perhaps `git push --force` or one of its variants (`--force-with-lease`, `--force-if-includes`).  But there is a lot to understand before you do this, and your question is quite unclear to me.

## Long

There are three parts to this:

1. Don't think about *branches*.  Think about *commits*.
2. Don't think about *changes;* think about *commits*.
3. Don't think about *remotes;* think about ... repositories.  Which are nothing but collections of ... can you guess?  Yes, that's right: *commits*.

In the graph image you posted, each round dot ● shown, no matter its size and color, represents an individual commit.  These commits are in fact numbered, though your image hides the numbers from you.  This is sensible because the numbers themselves appear to be nonsense, random gibberish.<sup>1</sup>  Humans don't normally want to look at the numbers.  We use the dots, or the commit messages, or something.  But the numbers are *everything* to Git itself: the number *is* the commit, in a very important sense.

That said, since the numbers look random and are useless to humans, we won't use them here either.  Just remember that each unique commit has a unique number.  What we'll do here, for discussion purposes, is give each one a unique *letter:* a single uppercase letter like `A` or `B`, or maybe `H` for *hash ID*.  The numbers are computed by using a cryptographic hashing function, so they're hash IDs.  Importantly, Git can only *find* a commit by its number.  So if we have a commit with hash `H`, and we want Git to be able to *find* that commit, we need a way to give Git the number `H`.

This is where *branch names* come in.  A branch name like `master` or `main` holds one (1) hash ID.  Your `main` holds hash ID `H`, which is the number for the red-dot commit.  But before we go any further, let's talk a bit more about commits.

---

<sup>1</sup>They're not random.  These numbers are carefully computed, and *every Git repository everywhere* agrees that *those* commits get *those* numbers.  No other commit ever, anywhere, gets *those* numbers: those are reserved to *those* commits.  That's why the numbers, which are huge and incomprehensible, have to be huge and incomprehensible: your commits, once made, have "used up" those numbers.

Technically, two different Git repositories could use the same numbers for two different commits under one condition: those two Git repositories must never *meet*.  But for practical purposes, the numbers are in fact unique to each commit.  That's why they're 160 bits long currently (and will be 256 bits long eventually).

---

#### What's in a commit

A commit consists of two parts:

- Each commit has a *full snapshot of every file*.  This snapshot is stored with the files compressed and de-duplicated, formed into a sort of permanent archive.  They're stored in a way that's quite useless for getting any actual *work* done: they have to be un-archived *out* of the commit first.
- Separate from the snapshot, each commit stores some *metadata*, or information about the commit.  This includes things like the name and email address of the commit's author.  It includes things like a date-and-time-stamp, for when the author *made* the commit.  It includes a log message.  And, crucially for Git itself, the metadata includes the hash ID, or IDs, of some set of *previous* commits.  We call these the *parent* (or parents, if there are several) of the given commit.

Most commits—including all the commits shown in your graph—store the hash ID of just *one* previous commit.  We say that this commit *points to* its parent commit, because the fact that the commit has this saved hash ID means that Git can then find the parent.  That commit, in turn, has a saved hash ID, which lets Git go one more step back, and so on.

The very first commit doesn't point backwards, for the simple reason that it can't.  When you made that first commit, there was no *previous* commit for it to point-to.

#### Let's return to your graph now

The name `main` holds the hash ID of some commit, which we'll call `H`.  So `main` *points to* commit `H`.  That's the red dot.

Commit `H` holds the hash ID of some earlier commit, which we'll call `F`.  So the red dot points backwards to an earlier blue dot.  That blue dot is the one closest to the labels `origin/main` and `origin/head`.

These labels—`origin/main` and `origin/HEAD`—are technically not *branch names*, but they serve a similar purpose.  They hold hash IDs.  We'll completely ignore `origin/HEAD` here,<sup>2</sup> and just worry about `origin/main`.  That name points to a blue dot.  We'll call that blue dot `F`.  It is (the hash ID of) a commit with a message that says `Update README.md`.

Commit `F` of course has a parent-commit hash ID; we'll call that `E`.  That's the blue dot one row down.  It has no labels but it too has a commit with a message that says `Update README.md`.  It points to an earlier commit `D`, which points to `C`, which points to `B`, which points to the very first commit ever, the one we'll call `A`, whose log message is just `Initial commit`.

I like to draw these graphs horizontally rather than vertically, when drawing them in plain-text on StackOverflow, where fancy graphics are tricky.  So I could redraw your graph here like this:

```
                      G <-I <-J ...
                     /
A <-B <-C <-D <-E <-F   <-- origin/main
                     \
                      H   <-- main
```

Commit `A` is the one with message `Initial commit`.  Commits `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, and `F` all have the message `Update README.md`.  Each of these commits is slightly different—they probably have different `README.md` files in their snapshots, for instance.  They definitely have different parent-commit IDs though, because the parent of `B` is `A`, while the parent of `F` is `E`.

Note that the name `origin/main`—not a *branch* name, but still a name—points to commit `F`.  Commit `G` is the one whose log message says `imadmini removing` and it points back to `F`.  Commit `H`, to which `main` points, says `main branch current changes`, and it *also* points back to `F`.  Commit `I`, which points back to `G`, says `ipadMiniRemoving`, and so on.

These different drawings—my text ones, and the graphical image you posted—both represent the same thing.  In yours, newer commits tend to be towards the top of the image.  In mine, they are towards the right.  The oldest commit, `A`, is at the far left.  But we use them the same way: we pick a name, like `main`, and use that to find a commit.  Then we use *that* commit to find an *earlier* commit, and work backwards from there.

The set of commits in the *repository* is the set of commits found by all the names, plus all the commits found by working backwards from these commits.  Typically, as we work backwards from some name, we join up with a stream of commits that we find under another name too.  Commits that we can find like this—in more way than one—are on *more than one branch*.  Commits that can only be found from *one* branch name are only on that branch, and if a commit can only be found without using a *branch* name, that commit is *not on any branch*.  Or is it?  This depends on what we mean by the word *branch*.

---

<sup>2</sup>`origin/HEAD` is a special case: instead of holding a hash ID, it holds the name `origin/main`.  That's why we would like to ignore it here, so that we don't have to worry about this particular special case.

---

#### Not all branches have branch names

This is where things get really confusing.  The commit *after* `ipadMiniRemoving`, which has commit message `imadMiniRemoving`, has *two branches coming off of it*.  I am going to get a little lazy now and draw my connecting arrows as lines, just like your graph viewer does:

```
                           M--N   <-- HEAD
                          /
                   G--I--J
                  /       \
                 /         K--L   <-- iPadMiniRemoving, origin/iPadMiniRemoving
                /
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- origin/main
                \
                 H   <-- main
```

Here, commits `M-N` can *only* be found by starting from the special name `HEAD` and working backwards.  `HEAD` is not a *branch* name.

As I mentioned earlier, `origin/main` is not a branch name, and neither is `origin/iPadMiniRemoving`.  Git has many kinds of names: branch names are just one *kind* of name.  The `origin/*` names are *remote-tracking names*.  They still serve to locate commits.  It's just that your Git creates and updates these names based on *some other Git repository*, as we'll see in a moment: if some *other* repository changes *its* branch names around, your Git will change your corresponding remote-tracking names around.

Git also has *tag* names, and tag names serve to locate commits.  So they're just as good as remote-tracking names—except that tag names don't automatically change just because some *other* repository has changed its branch names.  In fact, tag names should never change at all.<sup>3</sup>

Most people would call the series of commits that ends at commit `N` a "branch", even though there is no *branch name* involved.  Similarly, if we had a series of commits that could only be found by starting from some remote-tracking name and working backwards, most people would call those commits a "branch" too.  So if we're going to talk to other Git users, we have to get used to this idea, that branch names find commits, and this set of commits is "a branch", but so are some other sets of commits *not* found by branch names.  Moreover, when someone says "branch X", they probably mean *name* X, but when they say "a branch", we don't know what they mean without more information.

---

<sup>3</sup>This restriction—that tag names should never move—is something that humans have to ensure.  Git won't move tag names on its own, but humans can still move tag names, either on purpose or sometimes by accident.

---

#### The special feature of a branch name

What makes a branch name special is this: when you use `git checkout` or `git switch` with a *branch name*, Git puts you *on that branch*.  After `git checkout main`, for instance, `git status` will say `on branch main`.

Once you are "on a branch" in this sense, making a *new* commit *automatically updates the branch name*.  Consider for a moment a tiny repository with just three commits in it:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
```

If you're `on branch main`, as `git status` puts it, and you make a new commit `D`, this new commit `D` automatically points back to existing commit `C`, and Git then updates the *name* `main` to point to `D`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- main
```

This is how a branch grows.  But there is a catch.

The *way* Git handles this is by using the special name `HEAD`.  This name is normally *attached to* a branch name.  That's how Git knows which branch name to update.  Let's draw our three-commit repository again, but this time make two branch *names*, both of which select commit `C`:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop, main
```

If we're `on branch main`, we have this:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop, main (HEAD)
```

If we then `git checkout develop` to switch to branch `develop`, we get this:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop (HEAD), main
```

When we make our new commit `D`, we end up with:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        D   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

While `HEAD` remains attached to `develop`, the *name* `develop` itself has now *changed*.  It now points to new commit `D`.

#### You are in *detached HEAD* mode

Git has a mode it calls *detached HEAD* mode.  In this mode, the special name `HEAD` is no longer *attached to* a branch name.  Instead, `HEAD` points directly to a commit.  That is, the special name `HEAD` contains a raw hash ID, instead of holding a branch name the way it normally does.

You can get into this mode in multiple different ways.  The way you got into it is not as important as the fact that you did get into it, though in your case it was when you selected historic commit `J`:

```
...--G--I--J   <-- HEAD
            \
             K--L   <-- iPadMiniRemoving, origin/iPadMiniRemoving
```

This is what you called your "step 3", "**check out to old commit**".  By selecting this commit to pull out of the archives to work on, you got into the detached-HEAD mode.

You then made new commit `M`, which points back to `J`:

```
             M   <-- HEAD
            /
...--G--I--J
            \
             K--L   <-- iPadMiniRemoving, origin/iPadMiniRemoving
```

and then one more new commit `N`, which points to `M`:

```
             M--N   <-- HEAD
            /
...--G--I--J
            \
             K--L   <-- iPadMiniRemoving, origin/iPadMiniRemoving
```

and that's how you got into your current situation.

There is a big problem here, and that is that if you use `git checkout` now, you will *leave behind* commit `N`.  It will become hard to find.  Git *needs* the raw hash ID, whatever it is.  I have no idea what it is because nothing you posted shows it, and you probably have no idea what it is either.  So neither of us can provide the correct hash ID for commit `N`.  If you attach the name `HEAD` to some existing branch name, this writes the branch's name into `HEAD`, which loses the commit hash ID.

There are ways to find the hash ID, but rather than invoking any of them after *losing* commit `N`, it's better to put a branch name here *now*.  That's very easy at this point, because `HEAD` selects the correct commit.  This means that either:

```
git branch newname
```

or:

```
git checkout -b newname
```

will work.  The first creates the branch name, but does not check it out, so that you have:

```
             M--N   <-- HEAD, newname
            /
...--G--I--J
            \
             K--L   <-- iPadMiniRemoving, origin/iPadMiniRemoving
```

The second creates the name and then immediately attaches `HEAD` *to* that name, so that you have this:

```
             M--N   <-- newname (HEAD)
            /
...--G--I--J
            \
             K--L   <-- iPadMiniRemoving, origin/iPadMiniRemoving
```

If you plan to run, e.g., `git checkout main` next, it doesn't matter which of these two commands you use.  If you plan to make another commit, it's probably better to use `git checkout -b` so that Git will automatically update `newname` to point to new commit `O` once you make it.

## Your question

> So I need to keep the changes ...

Commits hold *snapshots*, not changes.  Git *shows* changes by comparing two snapshots, playing the [Spot the Difference game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference).

> currently in Head ...

Git is case-sensitive.  You should spell this `HEAD`, in all uppercase, always.  On some systems—e.g., you'll see this on Windows and macOS, typically—spelling it in lowercase or a mix sometimes works, but sometimes doesn't.  Don't do that; it's a trap because it will fail eventually, even if that's only when you try to do this on Linux.

> and remove above all commits from where I checkout in (3)

I find this rather unclear.  It sounds like you want to *discard* commits that, in the graph you posted, were laid-out above the point where `HEAD` shows up.  But there are no such commits: the name `HEAD` was just to the right of the topmost commit, the one I have been calling `N` above.

Nonetheless, here's the thing you can do:

- Git *finds* commits by starting from a branch name.  The name holds the hash ID of a commit.  That is, it *points to* the commit.  From there, Git works backwards.
- Hence, if there is a string of commits you want Git to *forget*, you just need to force the *name* to point to an older commit.

That is, suppose we have:

```
 ...--F--G--H--I--J   <-- branch-x
```

Suppose we convince Git to *move* the name `branch` *backwards*, rather than the more normal forwards movement that happens automatically if we `git checkout branch` and make new commits.  That is, we'll make the name `branch` point to commit `H`:

```
              I--J   ???
             /
 ...--F--G--H   <-- branch-x
```

Nothing about commits `I-J` has *changed*.  It's literally impossible for anything to change in a commit (which is what makes Git so good as a version control system).  But we *can* make them hard to find.  Now that there are no names that will let us *find* commits `I-J`, we just won't see them any more.  Eventually, Git will remove them for real,<sup>4</sup> but for now, just not seeing them is good enough.

---

<sup>4</sup>How long this takes, and the mechanism by which Git really strips out unreachable commits, is another question entirely.

---

#### How you can remove—or at least hide—commits in *your* repository

There are two simple ways to move a branch name.  Which one to use depends on whether that's the *current* branch name, i.e., whether you have that particular branch checked out.

If you're *not* on some branch name, the trick is to find the hash ID of the commit that you want the name to point-to, then use `git branch -f` to *move* the branch name there.  For instance, given our chain-ending-at-`J` above, we might run:

```
git log --decorate --oneline --graph branch-x
```

to have Git draw an ASCII-art diagram similar to the fancy one your picture shows, but that includes abbreviated hash IDs for each commit.  Then we pick out the commit we want the name `branch` to point to, and use cut-and-paste with the hash ID from `git log`.  Let's say that the abbreviated hash ID is `a123456`, so that our commit will be:

```
git branch -f branch-x a123456
```

The name `branch-x` now selects commit `a123456`, instead of the commit it used to select.  We can check with `git log --decorate --oneline --graph branch` again, to see that the last commit—the one found via the name—is now the one we want as the last commit.

If you *are* on branch `branch-x`, though, you can't use `git branch -f` to move it.  There are reasons for that (which we won't cover here).  Instead, you will need to use `git reset` to move the branch name.  The `git reset` command moves the branch name to which `HEAD` is attached.  As before, you need to find the correct hash ID.  This time, though, you need to supply one flag:

- `--soft` means *do the reset without disturbing Git's index or your working tree;*
- `--mixed` means *do the reset while resetting Git's index, but do not disturb your working tree;* and
- `--hard` means *do the reset while resetting Git's index and your working tree*.

That is, `git reset` first moves the branch name.  Then, it can go on to step 2: reset Git's index.  If it does reset Git's index, it can go all the way to step 3: reset your working tree.  The `--soft` option means *stop after step 1* while `--mixed` and `--hard` mean *go on to step 2 and stop* or *go through all three steps*.

When to use which option is another fairly long answer.  To have Git discard all vestiges of the work in a commit, though, we'll use `--hard` here.  So if you are on `branch-x` and want to make the name `branch-x` select commit `a123456`, you would use `git reset --hard a123456`.  Note that you do not specify the branch name here!  It is implied by the fact that you are *on* `branch-x`.

In any case, this is how you can re-arrange the branch names in your own repository.  Note that you will do this for *branch names*.  Other names—such as `origin/main` for instance—are your Git's way of remembering some *other Git repository's branch names*.  There is no point in fussing with your copies of their names.  You need to get *their* repository to change *their* names around.

#### Commits and branch names exist in each repository

As we just implied above, `origin` is itself a Git repository.  Technically, `origin` is your name for how you have your Git *reach* that repository.  So `origin` refers to a URL, and by calling up software at that URL, your Git calls up some other Git, that controls another repository.

You do this calling-up with `git fetch` and `git push`.  If you have been using `git pull`, you should be aware that `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command*.  It is the `git fetch` step that calls up the other Git: the second Git command is run locally in your repository only, after the fetch finishes.

When `git fetch` calls up their Git repository, their Git lists out their branch names and associated commit hash IDs.  Your Git checks your own repository to see if you have the commits, by checking to see if you have those hash IDs.  (This is why the hash ID *is* the commit, in a very real sense: Git only checks the ID.)  If you *do* have a commit, your Git tells the other Git: *I have that one.*  If you *don't* have a commit, your Git tells the other Git: *Send me that one.*  Their Git then offers the parent commit(s), and both Gits repeat all of this until they'll send you all commits they have, that you don't, that they can find with their branch names.

Your Git will take all the commits it needs and put them in *your* Git repository, and then create or update *remote-tracking names* like `origin/main` based on their *branch* names.  Your remote-tracking names will point to the same commit hash IDs that their *branch* names point-to.

The `git push` command is different.  Here, your Git offers their Git a commit, by its hash ID.  They either have the commit (and tell you that) or need it (and tell you that) and as before, your Git will send over whatever commits they need, if they don't have them.  But after that, your Git sends either:

- a polite request, *please, if it's OK, change your branch name _____ to hold hash ID _____*, or
- a forceful command: *change your branch name _____ to hold hash ID _____!*

When you run `git push origin main`, your Git sends the polite request.  The hash ID your Git sends is that stored in *your* branch name `main`, and the branch name your Git sends is the name `main`.  Their Git will *accept* this polite request under various conditions:

- you are the actual owner of that repository and/or are authorized to do this; *and*
- accepting this request won't cause that Git to *lose* any commits.<sup>5</sup>

If you're trying to get them to *drop* some commit, this won't work, and you will need the forceful command.

There are several improvements over the basic forceful command, but the basic one is just *set your branch name _____ (name) to _____ (hash ID)!*  If you use `git push --force origin main`, that's the kind of command you send.

When using forceful commands, you may want to verify that the commits you're having them *throw away* are the ones you *think* they are going to throw away.  For this, you can use `git push --force-with-lease` or similar.  See other StackOverflow questions for details.

---

<sup>5</sup>The way this is phrased is a bit sloppy.  Technically, they wouldn't lose a commit if they could find it with some other name, but they won't accept a push request that retracts the branch at all, even if they could still find the commits with some other branch name.  They'll only accept the push request if the hash ID is a descendant of the current hash ID.  This "is a descendant" test is Git's *fast forward* test.